Firebase Firestore Rules: Permission denied when trying to update documents
I'm getting a "permission-denied" error when trying to update a document in Firestore. I've ensured that my Firestore rules allow the operation, but the update still fails.
Here are the relevant Firestore rules:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Check if the user is an admin
    function isAdmin() {
      return request.auth != null &&
        get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == 0;
    }

    // Check if the user is a business person
    function isBusinessPerson() {
      return request.auth != null &&
        get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == 1;
    }

    // Rules for the clients collection
    match /clients/{clientId} {
      allow update: if isAdmin() || isBusinessPerson();
    }
  }
}

Here are the constants I use in the code:
const keyClient = 'clients';
const keyAddress = 'addresses';
const keyPhone = 'phone';
const keyName = 'name';

Here is the relevant update code:
Future<DataResult<ClientModel>> update(ClientModel client) async {
  try {
    if (client.id == null) {
      throw Exception('Client ID cannot be null for update operation.');
    }

    await _firebase.collection(keyClient).doc(client.id).update(client.toMap());

    return DataResult.success(client);
  } catch (err) {
    final message = 'ClientFirebaseRepository.update: $err';
    log(message);
    return DataResult.failure(FireStoreFailure(message: message));
  }
}

I've verified the following:

The create operation works as expected and follows the rules.
The allow update: if true; rule also doesn't work.
I've logged locator<UserStore>().currentUser! and FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser and they match.
Here is a sample of my log output for an admin user:
[log] admin: 0
[log] ClientFirebaseRepository.update: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.



I'm not sure what's causing the update to fail. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!
What I've tried:

Ensured that allow update: if true; is applied to see if it was a rule logic issue, but the update still fails.
Checked that create operations work fine, and removing permissions for create does indeed block the operation, so the rules are applied.
Verified that the user has an admin role (as shown in the log).
Logged both the UID from locator<UserStore>().currentUser! and FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser. Both values match, so they are not out of sync.

Why am I getting a "permission denied" error when trying to update documents, even when the rules seem correct and allow updates? Is there something I'm missing with Firestore security rules or the way the update operation is performed in the code?
I was expecting that the update operation would work since the rules should allow the update for users with the admin role or business role.

Keep in mind that we can only see what you shared, and the values of keyClient and some other variables are not present in the code in the question. If you can reproduce the same problem with hard-coded values for those (and any other) parameters, that'll make it much easier for us to follow along.

Second: there are 3 database write operations in the code you shared, across two different collections. Can you reproduce the problem with just 1 write operation? If so, please update the question to only include that code. Less code = more chance that we'll spot the mistake in what is present.

Third: are you sure that locator<UserStore>().currentUser! matches the request.auth that your rules check? I'd recommend logging the UID from your locator<UserStore>().currentUser! and from FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser to make sure they're not out of sync.

If you've tried allow update: if true; (assuming you've done it correctly) and it still doesn't work it means the problem is somewhere else, not at the firestore rules.
I would set allow read, write: if true; till it works and then try to modify the rules accordingly. Don't go at it all at once, try to isolate the issue.
